# angularjs: how to run view-embeded javascript after partial is rendered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, partials, ng-view

My view (a details itemId partial that lists img tags) is rendered from my controller.
The number of img varies depending on the model pointed to by itemId.
I need to change the div with which contains the ing tags to # of img x img width.

To do so, I need to make sure that my javascript in the view gets ran after the partial us rendered.

How to do that?

Comment: You can create a directive and set a watch on the "model pointed to by itemId" and in there you can change the div width, maybe after a $timeout if the dom isn't in the state that you want it during the digest cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do js in the view, all js must be on angularjs end controllers, directives, etc. A better approach is to use a directive else you could wait for viewContentLoaded like this:

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
    //Your js
});
```